# firebase rule to allow new user to create its account object when login the very first time

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this rule, it passed the simulated test but the client got the error "permission denied" after successfully authenticated using google.  The partial rule below check for the uid object inside users object, if it doesn't exist, it is allowed to create an object

```
!(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists())
```

The whole rules json is below:

```
{
  "rules":{ 
    ".read":"root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('roles/admin').val()===true || root.child('users').child(auth.id).child('id').val()===auth.uid",
    ".write":"!(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()) || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('roles/admin').val()===true || root.child('users').child(auth.id).child('id').val()===auth.uid",
  } 
}
```

The Angular code:

```
@Effect() loginGetUserInfo$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_GET_USER_INFO),
    map((action: AuthLoginGetUserInfo) => action.user),
    exhaustMap((googleUser: User) => {
        const ref = this.db.object('users/' + googleUser.uid);
        debugger;
        return ref.valueChanges().pipe(
            map((user: User) => {
        debugger;
                if (!user) {
                    console.log("Is a new user:", googleUser);
                    //ref.set(googleUser);
                    ref.update(googleUser)
                    return new AuthLoginSuccessful(googleUser)
                }
                return new AuthLoginSuccessful(user)
            }),
            catchError(error => {debugger; return of(new AuthLoginFailure(error)) })
        )
    })
);
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? What are you exactly trying to do? Can you explain it by decomposing your requirements in atomic steps? If I test your rules, they seem to fulfill the requirements (as I understand them): first time the user can write his profile and after that he cannot anymore.

Comment: I figured it out. The "permission denied" was from the read not write.   I fixed the read rule and now new user can create the profile.

Answer (score 0):

admin create new user from secondary app helped me.

```
      FirebaseApp secondary = Firebase.app('Secondary');
      final secondaryAth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: secondary);
      userCreds = await secondaryAth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
```